# Lubuntu 18.10 audio just disappeared

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 18.10

i'm new in Linux so i don't know so much about it, I had regular audio, but upon a few restarts, audio just dissapeared, i got windows installed too and there is normal audio, what can i do? Audio is not muted in alsamixer.

I reinstalled Lubuntu a few times and still is not working, but when i play music, pulseaudio bar "moves" (I don't know how to write this in english lol), it means pulseaudio recognize audio but there is no output? 
With Headphones it says "unplugged".

I appreciate your help